# PHP, Threads and curl

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, thread-safety

I have a php process which runs multiple threads, each of these Threads needs to make http requests via curl, using curl in each thread is causing problems since curl is not thread-safe, basically we the curl library crashes (i assume when 2 concurrent curls are executed), I would like to be able to independently use curl in each of these threads, my question is, is having a curl_multi resource for each of these threads and OK thing to do? Or will I have to create 1 curl_multi resource to handle multiple CURL requests and have something manage that? Obviously the latter option will require more work.. Any insight?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have implemente multi_curl, with 1 multi_curl in every thread, and so far in production has been working without issues, so for now I am concluding that it is safe to do so..

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you solution that I used to run curl in 200 threads. I am using Gearman:

http://gearman.org/

It can run your script in parallel very simple. And add new thread it is very fast process. In this case - every thread it is separated php process launched as:

`php file_path_to_script.php`